# RHDM 7.9.0 Imported Data Object cannot be parsed

Tags: redhat, redhat-containers, redhat-brms

I have a java class that I want to import into RHDM 7.9.0.  It imports but a warning message is displayed that the class cannot be parsed.  Once imported I am able to view it in the Source view but when I try to open the Model View it shows the message "Java file could not be parsed, it won’t be possible to open the Editor tab, use the Source tab instead."

Is this normal or is there something wrong with my Java file?

```
package com.cdm_testing;

/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private java.lang.String addressLine1;
    private java.lang.String addressLine2;
    private java.lang.String city;
    private java.lang.String state;
    private java.lang.String zip;
    private java.lang.String county;
    private java.lang.String country;
    private java.lang.String FIPSCountyCode;
    private java.lang.String FIPSStateCode;
    private java.lang.Double latitude;
    private java.lang.Double longitude;

    private java.lang.String addressType;

    private java.lang.Boolean validated;

    public Address() {
    }

    public java.lang.String getAddressLine1() {
        return this.addressLine1;
    }

    public void setAddressLine1(java.lang.String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }

    public java.lang.String getAddressLine2() {
        return this.addressLine2;
    }

    public void setAddressLine2(java.lang.String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }

    public java.lang.String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(java.lang.String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public java.lang.String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(java.lang.String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public java.lang.String getZip() {
        return this.zip;
    }

    public void setZip(java.lang.String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public java.lang.String getCounty() {
        return this.county;
    }

    public void setCounty(java.lang.String county) {
        this.county = county;
    }

    public java.lang.String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(java.lang.String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public java.lang.String getFIPSCountyCode() {
        return this.FIPSCountyCode;
    }

    public void setFIPSCountyCode(java.lang.String FIPSCountyCode) {
        this.FIPSCountyCode = FIPSCountyCode;
    }

    public java.lang.String getFIPSStateCode() {
        return this.FIPSStateCode;
    }

    public void setFIPSStateCode(java.lang.String FIPSStateCode) {
        this.FIPSStateCode = FIPSStateCode;
    }

    public java.lang.Double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(java.lang.Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public java.lang.Double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(java.lang.Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public java.lang.String getAddressType() {
        return this.addressType;
    }

    public void setAddressType(java.lang.String addressType) {
        this.addressType = addressType;
    }

    public java.lang.Boolean getValidated() {
        return this.validated;
    }

    public void setValidated(java.lang.Boolean validated) {
        this.validated = validated;
    }

    public Address(java.lang.String addressLine1,
            java.lang.String addressLine2, java.lang.String city,
            java.lang.String state, java.lang.String zip,
            java.lang.String county, java.lang.String country,
            java.lang.String FIPSCountyCode, java.lang.String FIPSStateCode,
            java.lang.Double latitude, java.lang.Double longitude,
            java.lang.String addressType, java.lang.Boolean validated) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.county = county;
        this.country = country;
        this.FIPSCountyCode = FIPSCountyCode;
        this.FIPSStateCode = FIPSStateCode;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.addressType = addressType;
        this.validated = validated;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question.  I imported the class into the com.myspace package but the class definition had com.cdm_testing as the package.  Once I changed the package in the Source view it became available in the Model view.